# How to run a script file on Mac?

Tags: macos

I have searched on how to run a script file on Mac but nothing works for me.

Every time I tried `sudo script-name` the terminal responds with

> -bash: /Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01: is a directory

The file I want to run is called `start` and it's located in `tesseract-3.01` directory on the desktop.

Answer (score 5):

simply do

```
/Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start
```

or if it's actually called start.sh

```
/Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start.sh
```

you might also want to do

```
chmod +x /Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start.sh
```

to change the script to be executable before you run the script

Comment: when i tried this /Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start
it responds with -bash: /Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start: No such file or directory

Comment: i changed it to be start.sh, now the terminal responds with -bash: /Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start.sh: Permission denied
unknown-58-b0-35-61-71-42:~ macuser$ !!!

Comment: then you need to do `chmod +x /Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start.sh` first. And then do `/Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start.sh`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo /Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start
```

You have to indicate the script name, but it looks like you were only specifying the directory.

You could also `cd` to the directory and then run it like so:

```
cd /Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01
sudo ./start
```

Comment: i tried this, the terminal asked me for a pw then it responds with sudo: ./start: command not found

Comment: That would mean it can't find a script called `start`.  But that's what you said you were trying to run in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo ./Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01/start.sh
```

or

```
cd /Users/macuser/Desktop/tesseract-3.01
```

then

`sudo ./start.sh`

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful :)